# trying to install specific version of a package getting error

Tags: centos, yum

Any reason I am getting this error?

```
sudo yum downgrade install ipa-server-4.4.0-12.el7.x86_64
Loaded plugins: aliases, auto-update-debuginfo, changelog, fastestmirror, filter-data, fs-snapshot, keys, langpacks, list-data, local, merge-
             : conf, ovl, post-transaction-actions, priorities, protectbase, ps, remove-with-leaves, rpm-warm-cache, show-leaves, tmprepo,
             : tsflags, upgrade-helper, verify, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.nexcess.net
 * extras: mirror.rackspace.com
 * updates: mirror.net.cen.ct.gov
0 packages excluded due to repository protections
No package install available.
No package ipa-server-4.4.0-12.el7.x86_64 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your command is incorrect - you can either use `downgrade` or `install` but not both.

Second, the correct name of the package is `ipa-server.4.4.0-12.el7.centos` and not as you specified (the suffix `.x86_64` is optional, but if you specify it you must do so after the entire version string, including the "`centos`" part) - and yum helpfully reported that it can't find a package with the name you specified.

To see the correct names of available packages, use the `yum list <package-name>` command. To create an exact version specification for downgrade, use the name from the list and the exact version string from the list, concatenated with a `-` (dash) character.

Here's how it looks on a CentOS 7 system when installing a specific version:

```
$ sudo yum install ipa-server-4.4.0-12.el7.centos.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.unifiedlayer.com
 * epel: s3-mirror-us-west-1.fedoraproject.org
 * extras: mirrors.sonic.net
 * updates: mirrors.sonic.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ipa-server.x86_64 0:4.4.0-12.el7.centos will be installed
```

... then a lot of dependency resolving followed by an installation summary and approval prompt.

If we try to install the latest version then use: `sudo yum downgrade ipa-server-4.4.0-12.el7.centos` to try to downgrade back to release 12, we get a lot of conflicts errors like these:

```
Error: Package: ipa-server-4.4.0-12.el7.centos.x86_64 (base)
       Requires: ipa-common = 4.4.0-12.el7.centos
       Installed: ipa-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.noarch (@updates)
           ipa-common = 4.4.0-14.el7.centos
       Available: ipa-common-4.4.0-12.el7.centos.noarch (base)
           ipa-common = 4.4.0-12.el7.centos
```

This is because the specific `ipa-server` version requires specific "sub packages" for for it to work and the downgrade command does not downgrade the sub packages directly. YUM man page has this to say about `downgrade`:

> The depsolver will not necessarily work, but if you specify all the packages it should work

The in order to downgrade you're going to have to specify all the "ipa" pacakges that cause conflict with the correct (older) version number, in the `downgrade` command.

Comment: still giving me the same error.  CentOS 7.

Comment: sudo yum downgrade ipa-server-4.4.0-12.el7.centos

Comment: @AndrewM: I've updated my answer to show how to install a specific version, and that works fine, but if I install the latest version then try to downgrade, I get errors - but completely different than what you specified. I'm editing my answer again with the additional information

Comment: @AndrewM - I've updated my answer with more details about `downgrade`. please make sure that you are *not* getting the "No package available" error - if you are, then you are not using the correct version string. If you are getting a "has installed conflict" error, then see my updated answer.